# Google map and openlayers

Tags: google-maps, openlayers-3

what is the ol3 (openlayers) equivalent of this google.maps event : `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'once' method of your map instance.

```
map.getView().once('change', fn...)
map.getView().once('change:resolution', fn...)
map.once('postrender', fn...)
```

More References [here](http://yaremych.blogspot.com.br/2014/11/openlayers-3-onload-moveend-events-geojson-kml-layers.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `load` event is called when the document has finished loading? OpenLayers does not provide an event for this, but you can use jQuery's [`$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).